# Read env variable from file

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerized php application. I want to set the version and the buildTime as a env variable from a file called version

```
VERSION=$(head -n 1 version) 

buildTime=$(head -2 version | tail -1)
```

The problem that it consider the dash in `-n` and `-1` as a special characters.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `consider the dash in -n and -1 as a special characters`, can't catch you, could explain more what does this mean? Please show your whole docker command, and also the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to imagine you have a file called `version` which ONLY contain the version of your system

Why just don't

```
VERSION=$(cat version)
```

If for some reason you have other information in this file, you can just use `sed`.

```
VERSION=$(sed '1!d' version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [--env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) option of [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) command.

- Create `version.env` file containing the required details

```
version=v1
buildtime=01-01-2019
```

- Specify the environment file in docker run command.

```
docker run -itd --env-file=/path/to/version.env image:v1
```

Hope this helps.